# PySpark on Jupyter Notebook, dataframe of two rows can't be converted to pandas dataframe. Why?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pyspark-pandas

This is the pyspark dataframe

[image]
[image]
And the schema of the dataframe. Just two rows.

Then I want to convert it to pandas dataframe.
[image]

But it is suspended at stage 3. No result, and no information about the procedure. Why this can happen?

[image]

And when I use pandas_api, the result is the same.
[image]

Why this could happen? It bothers me the whole day.

Could anyone help me?

This is the package version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try using this in first cell of notebook

import findspark

findspark.init()

findspark.find()

this will initialize the spark in jupiter notebook

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried but doesn't work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After trying and trying again, I found that the reason is that although runs in local mode, the source dir contains several parquet files. Then I need to convert it to rdd and coalesce into one partition. Then convert the rdd into pyspark dataframe. Then the pandas_api works fine. Wish this answer can help someone who met the same problem as me.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.